# Solve the following differential equation $ u_{xx}-m^2u=\delta(x-x_0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of following equation
$$ u_{xx}-m^2u=\delta(x-x_0),$$
$u(0)=0=u(L),\ x\in\mathbb R^2$

Actually, I don't know how to solve. Is there someone to help?

Comment: Helmholtz equation+Green's function + 1D +Google should give you an idea

Comment: Do you know weak formulations and weak solutions in the Sobolev space $H^1(0,L)$. If yes, then this equation has a well defined weak formulation, because the $\delta$-distribution is a bounded linear functional over $H^1(0,L)$. The last follows from the fact that $H^1(0,L)$ is continuously embedded in the space of continuous functions $C^0([0,L])$

Comment: Heuristically, you should solve $u_{xx}-m^2u=0$ with the initial condition $u(0)=0$ on $[0,x_0)$. Call the value approached from the left $u(x_0^-)$. (Note that this is unknown, because you do not have an initial velocity.) Then solve $u_{xx}-m^2u=0$ with the final condition $u(L)=0$ on $(x_0,L]$. Call the value which is approached from the right $u(x_0^+)$. Then adjoin the forcing to the problem by requiring $u(x_0^+)=u(x_0^-)+1$. This is not the only possibility; the weak formulation gives various alternatives, and the Laplace transform avoids the "piecewise" character of what I suggested.

Comment: Laplace Transform is the the easiest way to solve.

Comment: Try Fourier transform

Comment: I'm sorry, I made an error. You solve the equation on $[0,x_0)$ and $(x_0,L]$. Then you enforce the continuity requirement $u(x_0^+)=u(x_0^-)$ and you incorporate the forcing through the requirement $u'(x_0^+)=u'(x_0^-)+1$. Note that this might not be solvable, depending on the parameters. For instance, if $m=1$ and $L=2 \pi$, then the left solution is $A \sin(x)$ and the right solution is $B \sin(x-2 \pi)=B \sin(x)$. It's impossible for them to be equal and yet have different derivatives at $x_0$.

Comment: ...And I made another error, missing the minus sign in the DE. That fixes everything, because there is no way to have periodicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us temporarily assume that the solution can be extended over $R^+$. Next, apply the Laplace transform to the DE;

$$(s^2U(s)-su(0)-u_x(0))-m^2U(s)=e^{-sx_0}$$

Where, $$U(s):= \int_0^\infty \! e^{-sx}u(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

$$\Rightarrow(s^2U(s)-u_x(0))-m^2U(s)=e^{-sx_0}$$ $$\Rightarrow U(s)=\frac{u_x(0)+e^{-sx_0}}{s^2-m^2}$$

Applying the inverse Laplace transform yields:

$$u=\frac{u_x(0)}{m}\sinh(mx)H(x)+\frac{1}{m}\sinh(m(x-x_0))H(x-x_0)$$

In which $H(.)$ denotes the *Heavisde step function*. Imposing $u(L)=0$ with the assumption $0<x_0<L$ gives:

$$u_x(0)=-\frac{\sinh(m(L-x_0))}{\sinh(mL)}$$

Therefore, the solution is

$$u=-\frac{\sinh(m(l-x_0))}{m\sinh(mL)}\sinh(mx)H(x)+\frac{1}{m}\sinh(m(x-x_0))H(x-x_0)$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $u=G+y$, where $G=\frac{1}{4\pi |x-x_0|}$ solves $-u_{xx}=\delta(x-x_0)$ in the whole $\mathbb R^1$. Then plugging this in your equation gives   $-y_{xx}+m^2G+m^2y=0\quad (*)$ with new boundary conditions: $y(0)=-G(0)$ and $y(L)=-G(L)$. Now you have to solve the regularized equation $(*)$ for $y$.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right fundamental solution for one dimension? That seems to be the fundamental solution for three dimensions...